# I can't use the prompt app to connect my ios device

Tags: ios, localhost, prompt

I try to use my purchased Prompt to connect my jailbreaked iPhone. 
    host:localhost or 127.0.0.1
    port:22
    username:root
but it says that 
Connection failed 
Couldn't connect to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess you are using ios 7. I believe it is using a new sandboxing model for apps so they can't reach localhost directly.